# Connections not closing with Apache's worker MPM and mod_php

Tags: php, apache, worker

First off, I know this is a questionable setup, but performance of fastcgi or fcgid force me to give it a shot.  The problem is that my load testing never completes due to connections not closing.  When I push to only 40 concurrent connections, things go south - connections sit in an established state for several minutes:

```
netstat -an|awk '/tcp/ {print $6}'|sort|uniq -c
      1 CLOSE_WAIT
     72 ESTABLISHED
      8 LISTEN
```

Then after several minutes, they split into a mix of CLOSE_WAIT and ESTABLISHED:

```
netstat -an|awk '/tcp/ {print $6}'|sort|uniq -c
     41 CLOSE_WAIT
     32 ESTABLISHED
      8 LISTEN
```

And after 10 more minutes, this has not changed.  These are a combo of client to web server, and web server to mysql server.  If I test against a php page that does not make a mysql connection, everything works normally.

I custom-compiled PHP (configure below), and installed apache-mpm-worker via apt-get (Ubuntu 10.04).  I've tried compiling PHP with both msyql_config and mysqlnd for the mysql, mysqli and pdo modules.  Could this simply be a non-thread safe library rearing it's ugly head?

`./configure --prefix=/usr/local --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2 --disable-cgi --with-layout=GNU --with-config-file-path=/etc/php5/apache2 --with-config-file-scan-dir=/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d --disable-ipv6 --without-kerberos --with-pcre-regex=/usr --with-zlib --with-zlib-dir=/usr --enable-bcmath --with-bz2 --enable-calendar --enable-ctype --with-curl=shared,/usr --without-qdbm --without-gdbm --with-db4 --with-libxml-dir=/usr --enable-exif --disable-ftp --with-gd=shared,/usr --enable-gd-native-ttf --with-gmp=shared,/usr --with-jpeg-dir=shared,/usr --with-xpm-dir=shared,/usr/X11R6 --with-png-dir=shared,/usr --with-freetype-dir=shared,/usr --with-gettext --with-mhash=shared,/usr --with-ldap=shared,/usr --with-ldap-sasl=/usr --with-mcrypt=shared,/usr --enable-mbstring --without-msql --without-mssql --with-pspell=shared,/usr --without-mm --disable-shmop --enable-soap --enable-sockets --with-regex=php --disable-sysvshm --disable-wddx --with-xmlrpc=shared --with-iconv --with-xsl=shared,/usr --enable-zip --with-pear=/usr/share/php --with-tsrm-pthreads --enable-maintainer-zts --with-mysql=mysqlnd --with-mysqli=mysqlnd --with-pdo-mysql=myslqnd --with-libdir=lib64`

Comment: Can you add output from you httpd.conf file, specifically the MPM config?

Comment: For now, it's the default:  
    <IfModule mpm_worker_module>  
    StartServers 2  
    MinSpareThreads 25  
    MaxSpareThreads 75  
    ThreadLimit 64  
    ThreadsPerChild 25  
    MaxClients 150  
    MaxRequestsPerChild 0  
    </IfModule>

Answer (score 0):

One solution that worked for me was to add the following flag to apache setup (I dont use repo's):

```
export CFLAGS=-DNO_LINGCLOSE
./configure ...
```

This then forced apache to close the socket when a FIN packet was received from the Peer.

By default, Apache will put the socket into close_wait after the peer sends a FIN. At this time, the socket is considered half closed awaiting a FIN from the local peer, usually done by ending the application. Apache by default allows this to time out, usually 2-5 minutes depending on setup.

Comment: That's the strange part - here I am nearly 30 minutes later, and connections have not change (and won't until I restart Apache, which also isn't accepting new connections):

netstat -an|awk '/tcp/ {print $6}'|sort|uniq -c
     41 CLOSE_WAIT
     38 ESTABLISHED
      8 LISTEN

Comment: Sorry, wanted to add that the CLOSE_WAIT are port 80 from client, the ESTABLISHED are connections to mysql server.  So it's not closing the db connection as it should.

Comment: Are you running IPTables or some sort of firewall security service?

Comment: Not to mean that we're no longer experiencing the issue, but had to move on with another configuration.  I'd still love to circle back on this and try again.